# Convert TikZ to PSTricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, conversion

I'm an amateur user in LaTeX/graphics and I have a problem.
I designed the following figure :

[image]

by using the `TikZ` package:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\tikzstyle{lr2l2} = [rectangle, minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 1.25cm, text centered, draw = black]
\tikzstyle{lr2l1} = [rectangle, minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 1.25cm, text centered, draw = black]
\tikzstyle{lr1l1} = [rectangle, minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 1.25cm, text centered, draw = black]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\resizebox{7cm}{4cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm]
\node (in9) [lr2l1, below of = in1, xshift = 0.7cm, yshift = -1cm, rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split draw splits=true,rectangle split part fill={white,blue!30},rectangle split part align={center,bottom}] {$\mtc{X}_1$ 
\nodepart{two} $y$};
\node (in10) [lr2l2, below of = in3, xshift = 0.7cm, yshift = -1cm, rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split draw splits=true,rectangle split part fill={white,blue!30},rectangle split part align={center,bottom}] {$\mtc{X}_2$ 
\nodepart{two} $y$};

\node (in18) [right of = in12, xshift = -7cm] {text};
\node (in23) [left of = in12, xshift = -9.5cm] {text};
\node (in13) [lr1l1, below of = in9, xshift = 1.5cm, yshift = -1cm, rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split draw splits=true,rectangle split part fill={white,blue!30},rectangle split part align={center,bottom}] {$\mtc{X}$ 
\nodepart{two} $y$};

\draw [dashed] (in9) -- node [pos=1, anchor= south west] {text} (in13);
\draw [dashed] (in10) -- (in13);

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
```

Nevertheless, my supervisor thinks that I should redraw this figure by using the `PSTricks` package. Ι really have difficulty in doing this conversion.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Has your supervisor given you any reason why? I don't see any. Apart from the time spent on the conversion you would loose the ability to easily compile with pdflatex.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: One can easily compile pstricks code with pdflatex, if the relevant switch is set.

Comment: @Bernard You should trust me: it is not easy. You need something like auto-pst-pdf and there are quite a number of traps and pitfalls. You only need to search for auto-pst-pdf here on the site.

Comment: I never had any problem with auto-pst-pdf, personally.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: I can note that the TikZ code in your question doesn't actually work as shown, you refer to several nodes that are not defined previously (e.g. the first node is placed `below of=in1`, but `in1` doesn't exist).

Answer (score 7):

run with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`. Set `showgrid=true` to see the coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-node,array}
\def\Rectangle(#1,#2)#3#4#5{%
    \rput(#1,#2){\rnode{#3}{%
      \tabular{|c | >{\columncolor{blue!30}}c|}\hline
       \raisebox{-3\height}{$#4$} & 
       \raisebox{-9\height}{$#5$}\\\hline\endtabular}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](0,0)(8,5)
\Rectangle(2,4){R1}{\mathcal{X}_1}{y}
\Rectangle(6,4){R2}{\mathcal{X}_2}{y}
\Rectangle(4,1){R3}{\mathcal{X}}{y}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed,nodesep=0]{R1}{R3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed,nodesep=0]{R2}{R3}
\rput[r](0.75,4){text}\rput[l](7.25,4){text}
\rput(4,2.1){text}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer an automatic setting of the rectangles, use `\psmatrix`. Then you do not need any coordinate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-node,array}
\def\Rectangle#1#2{%
    \tabular{|c | >{\columncolor{blue!30}}c|}\hline
            \raisebox{-3\height}{$#1$} & 
            \raisebox{-9\height}{$#2$}\\\hline\endtabular}
\begin{document}

\psmatrix[colsep=1cm,rowsep=1cm]
[name=r1] & [name=R1]\Rectangle{\mathcal{X}_1}{y} &  
          & [name=R2]\Rectangle{\mathcal{X}_2}{y} & [name=r2]\\
          &                                        & [name=R3]\RectangleA{\mathcal{X}}{y}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed,nodesep=0]{R1}{R3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed,nodesep=0]{R2}{R3}
\rput(r1){text}\rput(r2){text}
\rput(!\psGetNodeCenter{R3}R3.x R3.y 1 add){text}
\endpsmatrix

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\xyBox(#1,#2)#3{
  \psframe(#1,#2)(!#1 1.2 add #2 1.5 add)
  \psframe[
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = blue!40
  ](!#1 0.75 add #2)(!#1 1.2 add #2 1.5 add)
  \rput(!#1 0.375 add #2 0.75 add){\large$\pazocal{X}_{#3}$}
  \rput(!#1 0.975 add #2 0.25 add){$y$}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(7.5,4.5)
  \xyBox(1.2,3){1}
  \rput[l](0,3.75){text}
  \xyBox(3.1,0){}
  \rput(3.7,1.75){text}
  \xyBox(5.0,3){2}
  \rput[r](7.5,3.75){text}
 {\psset{linestyle = dashed}
  \psline(2.4,3)(3.1,1.5)
  \psline(4.3,1.5)(5.0,3)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

Another solution with a short code, base on the `\psDefBoxNodes` command from `pst-node` and a `psmatrix` environment.:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-node,auto-pst-pdf, array}
\newcommand\myrectangle[2]{%
\tabular{|c|>{\columncolor{MediumSlateBlue!50}}c|}\hline
\rule[-7ex]{0pt}{15ex}$\,#1\,$ & \raisebox{-1ex}{$#2$}\\
\hline\endtabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
  \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=2em, rowsep=8ex]
    text\enspace\psDefBoxNodes{N1}{\myrectangle{\mathcal X_1}{y}} & & \psDefBoxNodes{N2}{\myrectangle{\mathcal X_2}{y}}\enspace text \\
 & \psDefBoxNodes{N}{\myrectangle{\mathcal X}{y}}
  \end{psmatrix}
\uput[u](N:tC){text}
\psset{linestyle=dashed}
\pcline(N1:br)(N:tl)\pcline(N2:bl)(N:tr)
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]